# Use VBA to re-arrange cells in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

Can i please get help in writing a Macro in excel to re-arrange cells and fill in the blank cells with zeros. I have attached an image that shows the cells before and after running the Macro to make it easier.

[Before and after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfXRq.png)

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to show the effort you have made to solve the problem before seeking help on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Macro is okay, but even without Macro, you can make this happen just using the cell formula.

So column A is date, column B is the label like (DATA 1), you just put following formula for next columns:

```
column C : =IF(RIGHT(B1,1)="1",1,0) 
column D : =IF(RIGHT(B1,1)="2",1,0)
column E : =IF(RIGHT(B1,1)="3",1,0)
column F : =IF(RIGHT(B1,1)="4",1,0)
column G : =A1
```

And then make the copy from C,D,E,F,G columns.

Comment: @TareqB why dont you make mine as an accepted answer and vote up ? :-)